# Can spring roo deal with gradle projects?

Tags: gradle, spring-roo

I wonder, that **spring roo** working with **maven** as build tool, and create maven projects.

Is gradle supported, or planned to be supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far I Know, there is no plan to support gradle. At least on 1.X and 2.x branch.

You can vote the [Jira improvement about it](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-1097).